# Schwa Sounds in American Accent

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent

I am new in America and I see most of the people use schwa sounds with most of the characters as p,w, k,c and so on. I wanted to know what all characters have the schwa sound and when and how to use it?

Comment: Use of the term 'schwa' is not entirely consistent -- do you mean the unstressed /ə/, as in the first syllable of *arrive*, which is what most people mean by 'schwa', or the stressable vowel /ʌ/, as in *but*, which some people also call 'schwa'?

Comment: @StoneyB i am not sure about it, but when i hear some of the american friends talking they say _talk_  as **thalk** or _prayer_ as **Phrayer**. thats what i am referring to.

Comment: Ah! - I think you are talking about "aspiration", the little puff of air which in English follows a /p/, /t/ or /k/ at the beginning of a syllable immediately before a vowel. If so, [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7321/32) may help you.